# How to pass parameter values to jenkins builds?

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to be able to write a comment on my GIT pull request that says "Run AUT for server 10" and that gets sent to a Jenkins build, and the build runs the automated ui tests for server 10. How can I send parameters to Jenkins build through a GIT pull request?

Comment: Are you talking about GitHub's pull requests?

Answer (score 0):

The comment in your pull request is (probably.. it may depend on which git service provider you're using) recorded as a commit message. So you can use a build task (Execute Windows batch command, Execute shell or similar) to grab that commit message and do further work.

You would use something like `git log --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline HEAD^..HEAD` to get recent commit messages. Everything after that is down to your script-fu!